# Python 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python

I have a nasty error in my code which I can't figure out on my own. Here is my code:

```
    accounts = open('usernames.txt').read().splitlines()
    my_accounts = random.choice(accounts)
    for x in my_accounts(starting_account, ending_account, 1):
        payload = { 'user_key': get_user_key(),
                    'terms': 'true',
                    'action': 'edit',
                    'page': 'simple',
                    'flow': 'TestA',
                    'dob': '1987-22-01',
                    'gender': 'f',
                    'name': str(x),
                    'password': create_password()}
        r = requests.post(CONST_URL + end_point, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=payload, allow_redirects=False, verify=False)

        if r.status_code == 302:
            accounts_output = 'accounts.txt'
            f = open(accounts_output, 'w')
            user_output = (str(r.status_code) + ' Account created succesfully: ' + str(x) + ' ' + create_password())
            f.write(user_output)
            f.close()
        else:
            print(str(r.status_code) + ' Unable to connect to the server :/')
            print(r.content)
```

When I try to run this I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Google Drive/testing/moreTesting.py",              line 66, in <module>
ms = accountCreator().account_creator(0, 5)
  File "C:/Users/Pieperloy/Google Drive/testing/moreTesting.py",      line 43, in account_creator
    for x in my_accounts(starting_account, ending_account, 1):
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Also, yes I did try lookup the issue but didn't found anything that could help me with my particular case. Thanks in advance, have a great day

Comment: Hmm... Are you sure that `str` isn't defined as a variable somewhere? Otherwise, your code should work

Comment: Your error message and the code posted here both reference different code! Your error message contains `str(ending_account)` and `str(starting_account)`, the code you wrote here doesn't. Please post the correct code snippet.

Comment: @soon: what about `my_accounts`?

Comment: @Zizouz212: no, because `my_accounts` is not a function, it is a string.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, you are right, missed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
accounts = open('usernames.txt').read().splitlines()
my_accounts = random.choice(accounts)
for x in my_accounts(starting_account, ending_account, 1):
```

`splitlines()` returns a list of strings. So your `my_accounts` variable will have a random string from your `accounts` list.

Hence, when you call `my_accounts()` in the for loop, you get the error that `str objects are not callable`.

Read more on [splitlines()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines).

Answer (score 3):

`my_accounts` is a string:

```
accounts = open('usernames.txt').read().splitlines()
my_accounts = random.choice(accounts)
```

but you are trying to use it as a function:

```
my_accounts(str(starting_account), str(ending_account), 1)
```

if you also have a function using that exact same name, you'll have to rename one or the other, you can't use the same name for a variable and a function.

Comment: Mmm, makes sense so how exactly would I go about getting the my_account variable inside the for loop? The 'usernames.txt' contains multiple lines of strings I wanna grab a certain amount of lines from that text file and then submit that.

The starting_account & ending_account are just integers so I can say like 'Hey make me 0 to 5 account' if that makes sense?

Comment: You don't need the random choice on accounts. You can change the for loop to `for x in accounts[starting_account:ending_account - starting_account]:`. This is called list slicing. Look it up.

Comment: @Naomi: glad you found both answers to be of help! Unfortunately, you can only mark one answer as accepted at a time; pick the one you feel helped you most. Not selecting either one is fine too, you are not required to select one!

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, both answers were indeed very helpfull and I wish I could accept them both.